# when changing text of ListView item it returns to the old one?

Tags: android, listview, textview

i am trying to change text of a ListView item , it changes successfully but when I click on any item on the list all the TextViews of the list returns to the old value , I've tried using GlobalLayoutListener but it takes too much work on the CPU .

the following code gets all the TextViews in the app and change the text of them all , but there is a another problem that i need to be fixed is that the text views that are not shown on the screen or when scroll down on the list,the list item text will not be changed .

```
ArrayList <TextView> textViews=new ArrayList<>();    
ViewTreeObserver vto = getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            changetext((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView());
        }
    });
void changeText(ViewGroup viewGroup){


    if (viewGroup == null) return;
    for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) changeText((ViewGroup) view);
        if (view instanceof TextView){
            if(!(textViews.contains(view)))textViews.add((TextView) view);
        }
    }

   for(int i=0;i<textViews.size();i++){
       textViews.get(i).setText("new Text");


  }
}
```

Comment: share your adapter code

Comment: Why don't you use an Adapter and change the TextView of an Item inside the getView Method of this adapter?? I think that it is easier that way. For an example using ListView with an Adapter and ViewHolder for the performance follow this link: http://www.ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

Its because the function is recursive. Try this.

```
ArrayList <TextView> textViews=new ArrayList<>();    
ViewTreeObserver vto = getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            changetext((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView());

/////////////Add here////////
for(int i=0;i<textViews.size();i++){
       textViews.get(i).setText("new Text");
  }
        }
    });
void changeText(ViewGroup viewGroup){


    if (viewGroup == null) return;
    for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) changeText((ViewGroup) view);
        if (view instanceof TextView){
            if(!(textViews.contains(view)))textViews.add((TextView) view);
        }//removed from here/////////
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class that extends `TextView` and override the method [onWindowVisibilityChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowVisibilityChanged(int)), it will tell you when your TextView is getting visible on the screen and  you'll be able to change the string at that moment.

If you need to change the text of the current activity, you could register them in a List (in `onWindowVisibilityChanged`) and just change the text of all these TextView.